# Array handling in powershell

Tags: powershell

Context :

I have a folder and have some files inside it. I am running a PowerShell script from Jenkins to delete the list of files selected from Jenkins and copy the fresh file from the source. I am trying to delete the files all at an time and copy the list of files like Ctrl+A and copy and paste. I have the script but it is doing individual deletion and copy-paste.

```
foreach ($database_filename in $database_files) {
    Remove-Item -Path $auditFile_Directory -Include $database_filename* -Recurse -Force
    Remove-Item -Path $logFile_Directory -Include $database_filename* -Recurse -Force
    if ($?) {
        log "Deleting the old files complete."
    }
    try {   
        log "File sets for $database_filename copying...."
        $primary_File = "$database_filename$primaryfile_extn"
        $audit_Files = "$database_filename$auditfile_extn"
        $log_Files = "$database_filename$logfile_extn"
        Copy-Item -Path $sourceFile_Directory$primary_File -Destination $auditFile_Directory
        Copy-Item -Path $sourceFile_Directory$audit_Files -Destination $auditFile_Directory
        Copy-Item -Path $sourceFile_Directory$log_Files -Destination $logFile_Directory
        if ($?) {
            log "A fresh golden copy of the db files created."
        } else {
            Write-Error "Failed! error creating the golden copy, please check the log files"
        }
    }
    catch [System.Net.WebException], [System.IO.IOException]
    {
        Write-Error "Failed! Unable to copy the SQL files"
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want transactional behaviour; i.e. so if there's a failure copying the second file, the first copy is removed so that it's as if the function hadn't been called?

Comment: Yes, and I am using an array function **$database_files** for it. So I want the deletion process will happen all at a time before the foreach loop on the basis of selection. For example I will put the below line before the for loop, If I select only 1 item it is working fine but for multiple item it is not working, because I am providing the file name from the list and it has lot of type with respect to that name like txt, pdf extn


Remove-Item -Path $logFile_Directory -Include $database_files* -Recurse -Force

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the code into two loops then, the first loop will delete all the files and the second loop will copy all the files.

Comment: It will delete on by one file is there any way like Ctrl+A and delete ?